# Spoon and Jacoco with gradle

Tags: android, code-coverage, jacoco, spoon

I used latest gradle version(3.3) and latest android gradle plugin(2.3.3) with latest jacoco version(0.7.7). I was able to get coverage reports and test results like a charm.

But the moment I added spoon plugin(I had not even applied spoon plugin but just added it to classpath in build script block) I started getting error with jacoco agent(`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_b0d6a23/Offline`). I saw multiple question about the error but none of the solutions work unless I used outdated versions of android gradle plugin and jacoco with spoon.

Please help if somebody has a real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs if jacocoagent.jar has a different version of Jacoco than expected by plugin(in this case spoon plugin). 
org/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_**b0d6a23**/Offline has different names for internal_**id**/offline for different versions of jacoco. That is why error is there.

If somebody else is getting this error, try running grade command from command line with --info flag and grep with "org/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_" to check which if there are different versions of Jacoco used.

Then check different version of Jacoco in your gradle dependency graph to check  which lib is causing problem.